# Extend User Model Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I'm starting a whole new project using Django 2.0 and python, so I'm at the beginning of deciding how to implement the Multiple User Types.

What I've read so far is that I can extend the User built-in model for django so that I would get use of django's authentication process, and create another models that links one-to-one with that user model. But actually I can't understand a little bit.

**My application has three user types: Participant, Admin, Judge, each of them will view certain pages(templates) and as well as permissions.**

Can someone provide me with the best practice/approach to start working on those user types.

Note: In the future, each user may have different fields than the other, for ex. Judge may have Join date while participant won't...etc

Comment: Django already has user "groups", which seems probably the best way, since you could have users that are admin and judge at the same time. Every group has permits that describe what users of that group can do.

Comment: No I won't have user that's judge and admin at the same time, I meant by multiple user types, is that i'm having different user types in my application

Comment: @OmarEl-elamy how about flags field? Look at `django-bitfield`

Comment: can you elaborate more @greesha0 ?

Comment: Permission are also mostly based on groups instead of users

Comment: Actually, if user can have only one type at the time, you can simply use `IntegerField` with `choices` argument. For more look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices. As for fields, that only available to specific user types -- you would need to overwrite `save` method of your model and do additional checks for user type there.

Comment: Provide me with examples please

Comment: @Greesha0 I can't understand your solution.

Comment: @OmarEl-elamy https://gist.github.com/anonymous/81013eff89b96a30043909fa1d17bdb5 But, as mentioned above, if you can, you should use groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) seems to mention what you are trying to do.

Here is an [example](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-django-user-model/) which creates custom user models. But I think you are essentially right. You can create an abstract base user with the standard information (name, email, etc). Then you can create a separate class which is just a model class, then set a foreign key to your abstract base user, and add additional data for that user.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    # etc

class Judge(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # User specific data
```

Hope this helps.